# Key doesnt turn- seems the wheel has locked

Tags: starting

I'm struggling to start the car as the engine won't start. It seems the steering wheel is locked

Comment: That sounds quite normal. Try wiggling the wheel as you turn the key, which should unlock it

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the steering lock has kicked in - this is a common anti-theft measure that most cars have in one form or another.

Usually you can free this by jiggling the steering wheel slightly as you try and turn the key.

Answer (score 1):

Try pulling hard on the steering wheel in one direction or the other, it should move about a quarter of an inch.  While doing this, turn the key.  This is a vehicle antitheft measure.

Comment: It frequently takes quite a pull to free the key, depending on how it was locked. I used to do customer service for an auto manufacturer and was surprised how often people would call in with this issue. Try pulling one way, if that doesn't work pull it the other way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility you moved the steering wheel a bit when the car was turned off. This can cause for the steering wheel to get locked. My car will automatically go on the steering lock when the steering wheel is perfectly straight, otherwise I have to wiggle the steering wheel a bit and hear a click --> this indicates the steering wheel is now locked.

Just wiggle your steering wheel whilst trying to (gently!) rotate your keys. The steering wheel lock should unlock.